# Manipulating roots of a cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $A,B,C$ are the roots of the equation $x^3-5x^2+x+1$, how do I find the value of $$\dfrac{A}{B+C}+\dfrac{B}{A+C}+\dfrac{C}{A+B}$$ I know the Vieta's formulas but I am not able to manipulate the above expression into something known. And taking the LCM doesn't help. Please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Vieta's, you know that $A+B+C = 5$. Therefore, we have

$\dfrac{A}{B+C}+\dfrac{B}{A+C}+\dfrac{C}{A+B} = \dfrac{A}{5-A}+\dfrac{B}{5-B}+\dfrac{C}{5-C}$

Also, you perform the following manipulation:

$x^3-5x^2+x+1 = 0$

$5x^2-x^3 = x+1$

$\dfrac{5-x}{x} = \dfrac{x+1}{x^3}$

$\dfrac{x}{5-x} = \dfrac{x^3}{x+1}$

$\dfrac{x}{5-x} = x^2-x+1+\dfrac{1}{x+1}$

Now take the sum of both sides over $x = A,B,C$ and apply Vieta's.

---

Alternatively, if $x = A,B,C$ are the roots of the equation $f(x) = x^3-5x^2+x+1 = 0$, then $x = \dfrac{A}{5-A}, \dfrac{B}{5-B}, \dfrac{C}{5-C}$ are the roots of $f\left(\dfrac{5x}{x+1}\right) = 0$. Apply Vieta's to that equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(A+B)(B+C)(C+A) = (AB+AC+B^2+BC)(C+A) = ABC+A^2B+AC^2+A^2C+B^2C+B^2A+BC^2+BCA = 2ABC + A^2(B+C) + B^2(C+A) + C^2(A+B) = 2\cdot 1 + A^2(5-A) + B^2(5-B) + C^2(5-C) = 2 + 5(A^2+B^2+C^2) - (A^3+B^3+C^3) = 2 + (A+B+C) + 3 = 2+5+3=10$